# Image received from API, showing blank image

Tags: flutter, dart

When I try to get an image from API it comes in as a list. In order to convert to A type List. I get a blank image and I am notified of this exception. How do make the image show instead of getting a blank Image

════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════
Cannot open file, path = 'https:.......amazonaws.com/Mealbox/e5585d92-fd5c-4e62-b17c-84f11127024d/image_picker4761428725156146366.jpg' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

Here is my code.

```
List<File> images = List<File>();
void sendDataForFourthPage(List<String> imagesIn) {
  images = imagesIn.map((e) => File(e)).toList();
}
```

FourthPage is for getting images from the gallery
Here is the code for the 4th page

```
class FourthPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FourthPageState createState() => _FourthPageState();
}

class _FourthPageState extends State<FourthPage> {
  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  // save the result of gallery fileUserOptions
  File galleryFile;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //display image selected from gallery
    imageSelectorGallery() async {
      galleryFile = await ImagePicker.pickImage(
          source: ImageSource.gallery, imageQuality: 20);
      if (images.length < 5) {
        images.add(galleryFile);
      } else {
        images.removeLast();
        images.add(galleryFile);
      }
      print("You selected gallery image : " + galleryFile.path);
      setState(() {});
    }

    return new SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 7),
            child: Text(
              "Upload Picture",
              style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Montserrat Medium", fontSize: 20),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
            child: Text(
              "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: "Montserrat Regular",
                  color: sankaraGreyColor,
                  fontSize: 12),
            ),
          ),
          new RaisedButton(
            child: new Text('+'),
            onPressed: imageSelectorGallery,
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 20),
          new Container(
            height: 2000,
            child: GridView.count(
              crossAxisSpacing: 6,
              mainAxisSpacing: 6,
              crossAxisCount: 3,
              children: List.generate(images.length, (index) {
                return Column(children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                      height: 90,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      ),
                      child: ClipRRect(
                        child: Image.file(images[index], fit: BoxFit.cover),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      )),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        images.removeAt(index);
                      });
                    },
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                      child: Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                        child:
                            Icon(Icons.cancel, color: Colors.black, size: 20),
                        widthFactor: 4.3,
                        heightFactor: 0.5,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ]);
              }),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget displaySelectedFile(File file) {
    return new SizedBox(
      height: 200.0,
      width: 300.0,
      //child: new Card(child: new Text(''+galleryFile.toString())),
      //child: new Image.file(galleryFile),
      child: file == null
          ? new Text('Sorry nothing selected!!')
          : new Image.file(file),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error message it looks like you're passing a URL to `Image.file`. That won't work because `Image.file` expects a file from your file system.
Use `Image.network` instead.

Comment: Yes, the main functionality is to be able to upload images from a phone(file system). But I also want to be able to retrieve previous images that have already been uploaded to the API and be able to manipulate them ie(remove add which is already being done). But I do not know how to structure my code to add the functionality of also pulling from API of already stored images